# Storing dates in postgresql arrays

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime

I have a large person-oriented historical dataset, which includes birth-dates recorded in YYYY, YYYY-MM, or YYYY-MM-DD format. I've been thinking I should use a date[] array for this field because the dataset frequently lists two or more birth-dates.

PG [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) say that ISO 8601 dates are supported, and ISO 8601 ([wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles)) accommodates reduced precision, but PG doesn't let me add a reduced-precision date (like 1882-11 for November 1882).

So, what's the best approach for handling records that need to contain multiple birth-dates that might look like 1883, 1882-11, or 1882-12-12?

Comment: If I understand correct when you save `1883` postgres save `1883-01-01`?

Comment: No. It returns a datatype error and inserts nothing. The issue is (I think) that PG does not allow reduced precision ISO 8601 dates, although I'd like to proven wrong:)

Comment: Assuming Pg does not support this, It's a pretty crappy workaround, but I would create three array fields, one smallint array and two date arrays, named bday_year, bday_month, bday_date.  This way, even when you see 1997-05-01 in the bday_year you know that it does not mean 5/1/1997, it just means 5/1997.  I realize it's far from ideal, but it will get you from point A to B.

Answer (score 0):

Lets imagine you have a table `person` with

```
+----------------+---------+----------+--------------------------------+
|      person_id |  fname  |  lname   |             bdate[]            |
+----------------+---------+----------+--------------------------------+
|              1 |  'Jhon' |  'Smith' | {1883, 1882-11, or 1882-12-12} |
+----------------+---------+----------+--------------------------------+
```

You dont want that because then is hard to search for one date or update the array.

Instead you want one aditional table `birthdays`

```
+-------------+------+------------+
| birthday_id | type |   bdate    |
+-------------+------+------------+
|           1 |    1 | 1883-01-01 |
|           1 |    2 | 1882-11-01 |
|           1 |    3 | 1882-12-12 |
+-------------+------+------------+
```

This way even when date is save `1883-01-01` you know will be `type = 1` or `1883`

Comment: There are a few problems with this as a solution, but the most serious one is that you're making up a birth-date of January first. The data only provides a birth year(1883). I really do need the ability to store reduced precision dates (which is per the ISO 8601 spec).